# ERROR @wdio/cli:utils: A service failed in the 'onPrepare' hook Error: Appium exited before timeout (exit code: 1) - Appium using emulator in VSCode

Tags: android-emulator, webdriver-io, appium-android

When trying to run I'm having the log below as `ERROR @wdio/cli:utils: A service failed in the 'onPrepare' hook Error: Appium exited before timeout (exit code: 1)`

package.json :

{
"name": "test2",

"version": "1.0.0",

"description": "",

"main": "index.js",

"scripts": {

```
"test": "./node_modules/.bin/wdio wdio.conf.js"
```

},

"keywords": [],

"author": "",

"license": "ISC",

"dependencies": {

```
"@wdio/cli": "^7.3.1"
```

},

"devDependencies": {

```
"@wdio/appium-service": "^7.3.1",

"@wdio/local-runner": "^7.3.1",

"@wdio/mocha-framework": "^7.3.1",

"@wdio/spec-reporter": "^7.3.1",

"@wdio/sync": "^7.3.1",

"chromedriver": "^89.0.0",

"wdio-chromedriver-service": "^7.0.0"
```

}

}

Comment: Can you post the content of your wdio.configuration.ios file or the content in your onPrepare() hook from this file?